# AWS CLI - How can I list all groups, users and attached policies in single command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-iam

I am trying to write a command in AWS CLI for IAM where i can fetch all groups details, users added in those groups and policies attached to those groups in single AWS CLI.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Answer (score 7):

Try this command:

```
for user in $(aws iam list-users |grep -i UserName|sed -e 's/.*: \"//' -e 's/\",//'); do 
    echo USER: $user; 
    aws iam list-groups-for-user  --user-name $user --output text|awk {'print $5'}; echo ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are no single AWS CLI command to fetch all groups details, users added & policies attached. You need to write either a small script using AWS SDK (E.g NodeJS) or a shell script with multiple AWS CLI commands.

Answer (score 0):

There is a single AWS CLI command which retrieves information about all IAM users, groups, roles, and policies in your AWS account, including their relationships to one another.

```
aws iam get-account-authorization-details > iam-details.json
```

You can read details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetAccountAuthorizationDetails.html